# Writing SQL subquery with CI4 active record

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm struggling to write my **sql statement with subquery** in Codeigniter 4 with active record.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.catId, p.image, c.id, (c.name) as category
FROM
    product_feature p
JOIN
    categories c ON p.catId = c.id
WHERE
p.id IN(
   SELECT MAX(p.id) FROM product_feature p 
   GROUP BY p.catId 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the subquery part, all parts are easy to write and straight forward.

The first step is to obtain an instance of the `BaseConnection` object, this is done by calling the static method `connect()` from the `Database` class which belongs to the `Config` namespace:

```
$db = \Config\Database:connect();
```

Now, you need to load an instance of the query builder class and pass it the name of the first table:

```
$builder = $db->table("product_feature p");
```

Now, you should use the `select()` method to write the `SELECT` portion of your query:

```
$builder->select("p.id, p.catId, p.image, c.id, c.name AS category");
```

After that, you have to use the `join()` method to write the `JOIN` portion of your code:

```
$builder->join("categories c", "p.catId = c.id");
```

Now we come to the interesting part, **How to write the subquery ?**

In fact, `whereIn()` method accepts the second parameter as an anonymous function that takes an instance of `BaseBuilder` which you can use to write the subquery, for example:

```
$builder->whereIn("p.id", function (BaseBuilder $subqueryBuilder) {
    return $subqueryBuilder->selectMax("p.id")->from("product_feature p")->groupBy("p.catId");
});
```

Let's put them all together now:

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table("product_feature p");
$builder->select("p.id, p.catId, p.image, c.name AS category");
$builder->join("categories c", "p.catId = c.id");
$builder->whereIn("p.id", function (BaseBuilder $subqueryBuilder) {
    return $subqueryBuilder->selectMax("p.id")->from("product_feature p")->groupBy("p.catId");
});
```

This will produce the desired result you're looking for, because if you use the method `getCompiledSelect()` on the builder instance, you will get the following result:

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`catId`, `p`.`image`, `c`.`id`, `c`.`name` AS `category`
FROM `product_feature` `p`
JOIN `categories` `c` ON `p`.`catId` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `p`.`id` IN (SELECT MAX(`p`.`id`) AS `id` FROM `product_feature` `p` GROUP BY `p`.`catId`)
```

I suggest you take a look at CodeIgniter4 documentation about query builder and anonymous functions:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: Thank you very much!! I get the explanation well. Thank you @Eyad

Comment: I had the same problem few days ago, which I have posted and its different to this. Please assist me with this. link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684901/using-active-record-to-calculate-profit-incomes-and-expense-codeigniter-4

Comment: @OneBuyu I'll take a look

Comment: @eyad-mohammed-osama I have kind help request for you , can you gently have a look at this https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=87747&pid=410046#pid410046 ? Thank you in advance if you may help.

Comment: @Robert Definitely !
I haven't used CodeIgniter in a while, but let me take a look

Comment: @eyad-mohammed-osama Thank you so much! Thanked you also on the forum.

Comment: @Robert You're welcome Robert!, That's my pleasure!