# Subqueries on CodeIgniter 4 using models

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am programming using CodeIgniter 4 and I am using CodeIgniter's [model](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html) as I understand it is a good practice to use it. It is a great way to do queries using one table very simple:

```
$this->myModel
         ->select('field')
         ->where('user_id', 1)
         ->findAll()
```

I don't even have to write the name of the table.

However, I am not able to do subqueries, in particular, I need `user_id` to be read from another table:

```
$this->myModel
         ->select('field')
         ->whereIn('user_id', SUBQUERY)
         ->findAll()
```

SUBQUERY is `select('id') from users where status='active'`.

However, this doesn't work:

```
$this->myModel
         ->select('field')
         ->whereIn('user_id', $this->userModel->select('id)->where('status', 'active')->findAll() )
         ->findAll()
```

Is there a way to do it with CodeIgniter's model or what is the best way to do it? Should I do the subquery with the Query Builder and mix it with the usage of the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing SQL subquery with CI4 active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795533/writing-sql-subquery-with-ci4-active-record)

Comment: `->whereIn()` accepts a callback as the second parameter in which you may define your subquery. Always read the docs first: [$builder->whereIn()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-wherein)

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Your suggestions are using Query Builder instead of CodeIgniter's Model, aren't they?

Comment: I found the solution checking again CodeIgniter's Model documentation.

In the subquery, instead of using `$this->userModel->select('id)->where('status', 'active')->findAll()` which returns an array of "user" objects (even if it is with a single attribute 'status'), which is not valid to use as a subquery, I found the existence `findColumn()` function of CodeIgniter's Model.  This way, using `$this->userModel->where('status', 'active')->findColumn('id')` is the solution.

Comment: This is the complete code for the example in my original question:

    $this->myModel
             ->select('field')
             ->whereIn('user_id', $this->userModel->where('status', 'active')->findColumn('id') )
             ->findAll()

Comment: However, this has an inconvenient: two separate SQL queries are generated, when checking CodeIgniter's debug functions. Does this perform worse than a single SQL query with a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:❌

```php
 ->whereIn('user_id', $this->userModel->select('id')->where('status', 'active')->findAll() )
```

Use this:✅

```php
// Get User table.
$userTable = $this->userModel->getTable();
```

```php
// ...

->whereIn('user_id',
    static fn(\CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder $builder) use ($userTable) => $builder->select('id')
        ->from($userTable)
        ->where('status', 'active')
)
```

[`$builder->whereIn()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-wherein)

> Generates a WHERE field IN (‘item’, ‘item’) SQL query joined with AND
> if appropriate:

> You can use subqueries instead of an array of values:

---

##### Addendum

In your particular case, you could alternatively use [`$builder->join()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-join)

> Permits you to write the `JOIN` portion of your query:

I.e:

```php
$userTable = $this->userModel->getTable();
$myTable = $this->myModel->getTable();

$this->myModel
    ->select(["$myTable.field"])
    ->join($userTable, "$myTable.user_id = $userTable.id")
    ->where("$userTable.status", "active")
    ->get()->getResult();
```

Comment: I like the second solution you propose because it uses models (no table names here) but I am more used to subqueries than using join for this. In the first one, however, I see too much code. A simple select-from-where SQL query becomes `static fn(\CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder $builder) => $builder->select('id')->from($this->userModel->getTable())->where('status', 'active')`.
Isn't CodeIgniter supposed to simplify writing SQL queries? For this particular case, I see that writing SQL query is more simple than the CodeIgniter code solution.

Comment: In the first solution I get this error: "Using $this when not in object context search". Is that the expected behavior or am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: In the second solution I get duplicated results when there are two references in the second table, that's why I though of a subquery instead of join.

Comment: @user1314836 In the first solution, please check my edited answer to fix the error. My bad.

Comment: Thank you. In any case doesn't look too intuitive for me, the advantages of models disappear. Finally I made use of getTable() for the two tables and I did a join + groupby on the first table. At least the query with CodeIgniter looks better:

 $table1 = $this->modelModel->getTable();
 $table2 = $this->model2Model->getTable();;
 $query = $this->modelModel->select(...)
            ->join(...)
            ->where(...)
            ->groupBy(...)
            ->findAll();